# Modify shorcut or executable?

Tags: car-dock

My car is a Chevrolet, and uses the Mylink radio system. It basically comes with some shortcuts (fixed) to run certain (limited) apps on an Android phone and show the phone's screen on the stereo car screen.

I want to run any app of the phone in the car screen.

So, my question is:

Is it possible to change the executable or shortcut on the phone to run another app?

For instance, my car can call an app called Bringgo. Can I change on the phone the shortcut or executable name to run Google maps instead Bringgo? So, If I tap the Bringgo icon on the phone, Google maps should run.

I think should be something like a symlink in Linux.

I have a rooted s3 mini, with CM 11.